# Jstree: Cannot read property children of undefined. Timing issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have an array of objects where each of them look like this structure:

```
var data = [{
"code" : "i1",
"name" : "Industry 1",
"parentCode" : "i0"
}, 
{
//and more items just like that one
}];
```

so I am using `jstree` to build a hierarchy view. Since `jstree` needs `id` and `text`, I map the `data` array like this:

```
datatree = $.map(data, function (item) {

        return {
            id : item.code,
            text : item.name,
            parent : item.parentCode

        };

    });
```

And then I initialize the actual tree inside my `hierarchy` div:

```
$('#hierarchy').jstree({

    "core": {
        "themes": {
            "variant": "large"
        },
        "data": datatree,
    },
    'check_callback': true,
    "checkbox": {
        "keep_selected_style": false
    },
    "plugins": ["wholerow", "search", "unique"]
});
```

This builds the tree and works fine when the original array is pretty simple, maybe one or two levels deep of parentages. However, if I test with an alternative array build exactly the same way, but with 5 levels of parentages, the console throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
```

And it's pointing to this row in the `jstree` original code:

```
k[c[o].parent.toString()].children.push(c[o].id.toString()),
```

I have the suspicion that it's a timing issue, as in `jstree` being unable to build the children array because there are still pending items to load. But I might be wrong in my assumption.

How can it be that the code works perfectly for arrays with simple parentages, but it breaks when there are multiple parent levels? Is it just timing as I guess, or there might be deeper issues?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184210/jstree-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-children-of-undefined), but it seems that the user was initially working with AJAX and solved the problem declaring a local object. Mine is already local and it actually works in some cases, so I am not sure what's going on.

Comment: it's best if you reproduce the error in a jsFiddle (or in a runnable snippet here on SO). Having a fixture against which to debug is necessary to help you here.

Comment: Can you post an example of multilevel source array that doesn't work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That error happens with me when, in your code:

```
{
  id : item.code,
  text : item.name,
  parent : item.parentCode
};
```

Your parent has an id of to a non-existent item.
The parent key must exist, and won't accept false, null, 0, or an id that isn't in the data list. If an item has no parent, the parent needs to be "#", i.e. `"parent": "#"`.

So:

- Check items with parent null or undefined;
- Check items with parent without corresponding parent